# If Toggle() class hidden uncheck the radio button if toggle class visible check the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not good at Jquery but trying to fix something, I have a toggle function showing the div on checking a checkbox and hide the div on un-checking the checkbox, in the div I have radio button value LEFT, WHOLE, RIGHT. What Im trying to do is when someone check the checkbox it toggle the div and "WHOLE" option should select by default from radio box and this option deselect when toggle is hidden.

I have below code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    $("input:radio[value='whole']").attr('checked',true);

});});
```

Problem is when toggle show the div it check the WHOLE in button but it effect on all other hidden divs. I want to select WHOLE only for that div which is toggled and rest are remain unchecked.

I have searched the whole internet but not found anything, again I am not Jquery expert I am internee.

http://dhowcruisemarina.com/pizza/product/build-your-own-pizza/ here once you check the Olives from the option "VEGGIES & GOOD STUFF " all its options (radio buttons) will toggle and I want to check WHOLE only for olives. In my case all other hidden divs options are selected as WHOLE and shows in the Checkout Page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the specific radio button.

`$("input:radio[value='whole']")` This targets every radio input with a value of 'whole'

I can't give the exact answer without seeing your HTML but basically you need to target the radio button with a value of whole in the specific div only like this

`$("#divId > input:radio[value='whole']")`

https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: http://dhowcruisemarina.com/pizza/product/build-your-own-pizza/

here once you check the Olives from the option "VEGGIES & GOOD STUFF
" all its options will toggle and I want to check WHOLE only for olives in my case all other hidden options are selected as WHOLE